# SPTrustedRootAuthority from Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, x509certificate

How can I import the certificates to SharePoint 2010 (the certs that will be used for the trusted identity provider, and it is a chain cert) using c# and SharePoint 2010 apis?

PowerShell has New-SPTrustedRootAuthority, but I cant use powershell. 
I use reflection on the dll, and New-SPTrustedRootAuthority is using SPTrustedRootAuthorityManager class which is internal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This will add the specified X509 certificate to SharePoint 2010's 'Trusted Relationships' store.

**Usage**

```cs
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\my_cert.cer");

AddTrustedRootAuthority("My Cert", cert);
```

**Util**

```cs
public static void AddTrustedRootAuthority(string name, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    Type SPTrustedRootAuthorityManagerType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTrustedRootAuthorityManager, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", true);
    Type SPTrustedRootAuthorityType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTrustedRootAuthority, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", true);

    object manager = SPTrustedRootAuthorityManagerType.GetProperty("LocalOrThrow", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);

    object authority = Activator.CreateInstance(SPTrustedRootAuthorityType, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { name, manager, certificate }, null);

    SPTrustedRootAuthorityType.GetMethod("Update", Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(authority, null);
}
```